# What am i doing wrong there? error "index out of range" trying to fill a list with lists

Tags: python

I want to do a list with lists inside, with a for and i get index out of range

I tryed with empleados.append() but it doesnt work

```py
def main():
    empleados=[]
    for i in range(1):
        empleados[i][0](input("Ingrese el Nombre: "))
        empleados[i][1](input("Ingrese el Apellido: "))
        empleados[i][2](int(input("Ingrese el Sueldo Base: ")))
        empleados[i][3](int(input("Ingrese el AFP 1 o 2: ")))
        empleados[i][4](datetime(int(input("Ingrese la Fecha de Ingreso(pulsa intro cada vez 2000 12 31): ")),int(input("/")),int(input("/"))))
        empleados[i][5](int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de hijos que tiene: ")))
```

Comment: "I tryed with empleados.append() but it doesnt work" - you should try again because this is the only way to append one new item to a list

Comment: initialise `empleados = [[]]` first, then you can do `empleados[0].append(input(...))` as often as you want.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to SO!

There's no list at `empleados[0]` to insert new values into. I find something like this is a little easier to read:

```
def main():
    empleados=[]
    for i in range(1):
        empleado_nueva = []
        empleado_nueva.append(input("Ingrese el Nombre: "))
        empleado_nueva.append(input("Ingrese el Apellido: "))
        empleado_nueva.append(int(input("Ingrese el Sueldo Base: ")))
        empleado_nueva.append(int(input("Ingrese el AFP 1 o 2: ")))
        empleado_nueva.append(datetime(int(input("Ingrese la Fecha de Ingreso(pulsa intro cada vez 2000 12 31): ")),int(input("/")),int(input("/"))))
        empleado_nueva.append(int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de hijos que tiene: ")))
        empleados.append(empleado_nueva)
    return empleados
```

It's worth mentioning that the index-access pattern you're attempting (`empleados[i][0] = ...`) only works if there's something already at that index, for instance:

```
>>> x = []
>>> x[0] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> x[0] = 'd'
>>> x
['d', 'b', 'c']
```

So the append's are probably the best way to go.

Comment: Hm. Where do you `return empleados`? I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying use empleados[i] as a list with an existing index you can insert into, when at the moment, it's not.

You need to set up your variables a separate list and then append them. E.g.

```
def main():
    empleados=[]
    vars = [
        input("Ingrese el Nombre: "),
        input("Ingrese el Apellido: "),
        int(input("Ingrese el Sueldo Base: ")),
        int(input("Ingrese el AFP 1 o 2: ")),
        datetime(int(input("Ingrese la Fecha de Ingreso(pulsa intro cada vez 2000 12 31): ")),int(input("/")),int(input("/"))),
        int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de hijos que tiene: ")
    empleados.append(vars)
```